# To prove either $p$ or $q$ (exclusive or), does it suffice to prove only one being true?

Tags: logic, proof-writing

For instance by defining $$\forall (a,b)\in \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}:a<b\iff \exists c\in \mathbb{N}:a+c=b$$
If I am try prove either $0<1$ or $0=1$. Does it suffice to show $0<1$ by means of the foregoing definition? Should I also prove $0\ne 1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also prove $0\ne1$.

By the way, your definition must be corrected a bit: $\forall(a,b)\in\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}:a<b\Longleftrightarrow\exists c\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}:a+c=b.$

Otherwise, $1=1+0<1.$